# List not being updated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a cryptocurrencies price tracker and am implementing data sorting on the page. At first, I'm trying to sort items by ranking order, using javascript's .reverse() method, but react is not updating the view. The array is being updated, but it is not being shown on the page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Title,
  Container,
  Logos,
  Names,
  Form,
  FormItem,
  ItemWrapper,
  IdWrapper
} from "./HomeStyles";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([]);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&&?order=market_cap_asc&&per_page=50&&page=1"
      );
      const data = response.data;
      setCurrencies(data);
      setLoaded(true);
    };
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const reverseCurrencies = () => {
    setCurrencies(currencies.reverse());
    console.log(currencies);
  };

  const labels = ["Name", "Market Cap (USD)", "Price (USD)", "24h Change (%)"];

    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>Top 50 cryptocurrencies by market capitalization</Title>
        <Form>
          <FormItem>
            <IdWrapper
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={reverseCurrencies}
            >
              <p>RANK</p>
            </IdWrapper>

            {labels.map(label => {
              if (label === "24h Change (%)") {
                return (
                  <ItemWrapper last key={label}>
                    <p>{label}</p>
                  </ItemWrapper>
                );
              } else {
                return (
                  <ItemWrapper key={label}>
                    <p>{label}</p>
                  </ItemWrapper>
                );
              }
            })}
          </FormItem>

          {currencies.map(coin => (
            <FormItem key={coin.id}>
              <IdWrapper>
                <span>{coin.market_cap_rank}</span>
              </IdWrapper>
              <ItemWrapper>
                <Logos src={coin.image} alt={coin.name} />
                <Names>{coin.name}</Names>
              </ItemWrapper>
              <ItemWrapper>
                <p
                  className={
                    coin.price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? "red" : "green"
                  }
                >
                  $
                  {coin.market_cap
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,")}
                </p>
              </ItemWrapper>
              <ItemWrapper>
                <p
                  className={
                    coin.price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? "red" : "green"
                  }
                >
                  $
                  {coin.current_price
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,")}
                </p>
              </ItemWrapper>
              <ItemWrapper last>
                <p
                  className={
                    coin.price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? "red" : "green"
                  }
                >
                  {coin.price_change_percentage_24h
                    .toFixed(2)
                    .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,")}
                  %
                </p>
              </ItemWrapper>
            </FormItem>
          ))}
        </Form>
      </Container>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

In the reverseCurrencies function, the currencies array is being logged to the console and is correctly reversed. To check out the complete code (It may not have this part of the code since it's broken.), you can go to this link -> https://github.com/Arthur-Serafim/cryptocurrency-tracker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reverse` does [inplace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) array mutation. Copy array before reversing

```
setCurrencies(currencies.slice(0).reverse());
```

Comment: Didn't know this was a thing, it was really helpful! After your comment, I tried to clone the array with the spread operator and also worked. Thanks

Comment: Yeah `[...currencies]` also effectively clones an array but it does much more under the hood :)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. When dealing with spread, it was taking longer to update the list